# How to format numbers to block of length three separated by comma, last 2 blocks or last block can be length of two but it cannot be length of one

Tags: javascript, string-formatting

Need to format the number into blocks of a length of three, separated with commas.
If required, the second last block can be of length two, like 987,234,65,43
The last block cannot be of length one(046,435,699,8).
The last block should be a length of two or three, it should not be one.

Examples:
"223,334,874,498"
"987,234,65,43"
"487,534,354,23"

Below is the code, but in this code, I am not able to make that last block to the length of 2 or 2 digits.
For "0464356998" ---Current Output is:046,435,699,8 ---
But Expected Output is: 046,435,69,98

```
function format(N) {     

    return N.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') 
    // Replace everything which are not a number   

    // Spilt on every 3rd number
    .match(/\d{1,3}/g)  

    // Join with commas
    .join(',')     
    }
    console.log(format("0464356998"));
    //Current output:  046,435,699,8
    //expected Output: 046,435,69,98
```

Comment: I don’t think it makes sense to try and cram this requirement into regex. Do the math first - length of your input string modulo 3, if that yields 1, then you know you have a case where you need to make the last two elements contain two digits each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is best way but `n` is **string** so you can [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)  and you can count `length` of string

```js
function format(n) {  
  if((n.length - 6) % 2 === 0){ // is (n.length - 6) is divisible without remainder
    return `${n.slice(0,3)}, ${n.slice(3,6)}, ${n.slice(6,8)}, ${n.slice(8,10)}`
  }else{
    return `${n.slice(0,3)}, ${n.slice(3,6)}, ${n.slice(6,9)}, ${n.slice(9,12)}`
  }
}


console.log(format("0464356998"));
console.log(format("04643569981"));
```

**UPD** For any string from 6 to ...

```js
function formatter(n) {
    let a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n.length / 3; i++) {
      a.push(n.slice(i * 3, (i + 1) * 3));
    }

    if (a[a.length - 1].length === 1){
      let b = a[a.length - 2].substring(2,3)
      let c = a[a.length - 1];
      a[a.length - 2] = a[a.length - 2].slice(0, 2);
      a[a.length - 1] = b.concat(c);
    }
    return a.join();
  }
  console.log(formatter("0464356998")); // 10
  console.log(formatter("04643569982")); // 11
  console.log(formatter("046435699823")); // 12
  console.log(formatter("0464356998231")); // 13
  console.log(formatter("04643569982316")); // 14
  console.log(formatter("046435699823156")); // 15
  console.log(formatter("0464356998231675")); // 16
  console.log(formatter("04643569982315634")); // 17
  console.log(formatter("046435699823167556")); // 18
  console.log(formatter("046435699810464356998")); // 21
  console.log(formatter("0464356998104643569981")); // 22
```

Comment: Thank You @Greg. It's Working perfectly. Can you please explain what this statement does ((n.length - 6) % 2 === 0) ----why n.length - 6. what does this 6 indicates.

Comment: I just skip first 6 strings))) in string `"0464356998"` its check only `"6998"` because first 6 digits (strings) always present (`"0464356998".length = 10, 10-6 = 4, 4%2 = 0`)

Comment: for string with length 11 `"04643569981"` same: `"04643569981".length = 11, 11-6 = 5, 5%2 = 1`

Comment: But it's not working for "0464356998104643569981"

Comment: How match digits can be in string? For any length must be end with `000, 00` or `00, 00`?

Comment: Yes, how it possible for this--- For any length 000,00,00 and 000,000,000,000,000,00,00.

Comment: please help....I mean the length can be any, length is not limited, in that case what will be the code for that

Comment: @aish check post, i add for any string